# Fire load event of CrystalReportViewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am working on Windows application. Trying to call load event of Crystal Report Viewer on button click  but could not get success. i want to call BillViewer_Load on button click. please help.
event for button click

```
private void BtnShowbill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Report load event

```
private void BillViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Hi will better put all your code in public void and after call that method inside event onclick from your button

Comment: @Ryuzaki i am loading crystal report on BillViewer_Load event and after click on button i want print direct without showing of report viewer.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void BtnShowbill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BillViewer_Load();
}
```

Comment: Well my friend, of course it is not working because you have nothing in your BillViewer_Load. Your question was how to fire the load event from a button click, and that's what I showed you.

Comment: So do you need help with the BillViewer_Load event as well?